# how to highlight/change color to particular word in a table in html5?

Tags: html, kdb

If there is a table, and the last column is called result.
I want to highlight all the cell/text that has "Failed".

How can I do that?

I need to use html5 with a table from kdb.

Currently my email function is this

```
htmlMailBody:{[emailadd;subject;message]
cmd:"echo \"",message, "\" | mutt -e  \"my_hdr 
From:abc@gmail.com\" -e \"my_hdr Content-Type: 
text/html\" ",emailadd, " -s \"",subject,"\"";
sent:@[{system x;1b};cmd;{.log.error"Failure sending email. Reason: ",x;0b}];
 if[sent; .log.info "Sent email to ",emailadd ];
};



mailRCP:bbc.gmail.com



htmlMailBody[mailRCP ;"health check";(,/)("<h2>SOD CHECKS<hr /></h2>";"<br />";markup[result];"<br />")];
```

This didnt work. if replace markup[result] with a kdb table it will work.

Comment: what you want to do ??

Comment: I want to highlight the word "failed" in the table with red color.

Comment: You can easily do this using bootstrap alert !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To markup your HTML table direct from q, use the markup functions in the [`.h` namespace](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth).

Let your table be `t`.

```
q)t
a  b  c  d  result
-------------------
94 66 8  82 success
8  24 62 47 failed
97 60 95 26 success
52 69 59 93 success
```

Make a corresponding table `at` of attributes for the HTML `td` elements. Start with empty dictionaries, for no attributes. An empty dictionary is `()!()`.

```
q)show at:flip (cols t)! (count each(cols t;t))#enlist ()!()
a     b     c     d     result
------------------------------
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
```

Update the `result` column of `at` according to the `result` column of `t`.

```
q)f:t[`result]=`failed
q)update result:([]color:(sum f)#enlist"red")from `at where f
q)at
a     b     c     d     result
----------------------------------------
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() (,`color)!,"red"
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!() ()!() ()!() ()!()
```

We can use [`.h.htac`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/doth/#hhtac-element) to mark up the table cells with the attribute dictionaries. First the table cells as strings:

```
q)string t cols t
"94"      ,"8"     "97"      "52"
"66"      "24"     "60"      "69"
,"8"      "62"     "95"      "59"
"82"      "47"     "26"      "93"
"success" "failed" "success" "success"
```

Never mind that they’ve been flipped. Now the dictionaries from `at` – also flipped.

```
q)at cols t
()!() ()!()            ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!()            ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!()            ()!() ()!()
()!() ()!()            ()!() ()!()
()!() (,`color)!,"red" ()!() ()!()
```

We can use these as the second and first arguments respectively of `.h.htac`. The [*each-both* adverb](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both) will iterate over corresponding rows, but we want corresponding cells, so `.h.htac''` to iterate within cells within rows.

```
q).h.htac''[`td;at cols t;string t cols t]
"<td>94</td>"      "<td>8</td>"                    "<td>97</td>"      "<td>52..
"<td>66</td>"      "<td>24</td>"                   "<td>60</td>"      "<td>69..
"<td>8</td>"       "<td>62</td>"                   "<td>95</td>"      "<td>59..
"<td>82</td>"      "<td>47</td>"                   "<td>26</td>"      "<td>93..
"<td>success</td>" "<td color=\"red\">failed</td>" "<td>success</td>" "<td>su..
```

Function `markup` assembles the HTML `table` element:

```
markup:{[t]
  th:.h.htc[`tr;]raze .h.htc[`th;] each string cols t;                           / table head
  at:flip (cols t)! (count each(cols t;t))#enlist ()!();                         / empty attribute dictionaries
  f:t[`result]=`failed;
  at:update result:([]color:(sum f)#enlist"red")from at where f;                 / attributes for result failed
  tr:.h.htc[`tr;]each raze each flip .h.htac''[`td;at cols t;string t cols t];   / table rows
  .h.htc[`table;] .h.htc[`thead;th],.h.htc[`tbody;raze tr]
  }
```

Using a **table of attribute dictionaries** is a robust technique that can be adapted to all kinds of highlighting, or providing IDs for client-side scripts.

Comment: Thanks!!!! i have a function that can send the email and just need to put the content in. when I put the content markup[table] it didnt work. should there be a comma between .h.htc[`table;] .h.htc[`thead;th]? is this producing a table or a page?? Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: I updated my question. If you dont mind, can you please take look? Thanks!

Comment: Corrected. (Apologies: I’d pasted in a version prior to the one I tested.) Now returns a single string, suitable for the 3rd argument of `htmlMailBody`.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:50px;">
<div class="container">
 
  <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Success !!</strong> This Text When Success !!
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">×</a>
    <strong>Failed !!</strong> This Text When Failed !!
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks!! I mean in a table, there will be many columns. and the last column is called result. Each cell will be only success or failed. I want to highlight those with words caled "failed"

Comment: @Terry Check The  `John Doherty` Ans Its Simple way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Add the result as a HTML5 `data-` attribute to each cell:

```css
.results td[data-status="Failed"] {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<table class="results">
    <tr>
        <th>Test Name</th>
        <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 1</td>
        <td data-status="Passed">Passed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 2</td>
        <td data-status="Failed">Failed</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test 3</td>
        <td data-status="Passed">Passed</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by jQuery. See below code. Hope it will work. if you got any jQuery error, then replace all `$` to `jQuery`. and bound your result text with an html element with `result_text` class.

HTML

```
<td><div class='result_text'>Failed</div></td>
<td><div class='result_text'>Success</div></td>
<td><div class='result_text'>Failed</div></td>

$(".result_text").each(function() {
   if($(this).text()=='Failed'){
      $(this).parent().addClass('bg-danger');
   }else{
       $(this).parent().addClass('bg-success');
   }
})
```